# Event listeners don't get re-attached to my HTML elements when using ES6 without re-feshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, function, ecmascript-6, event-listener

I am printing a simple string to the screen. When clicking on one of its letters, is should be removed from wherever it is the string and added at the end. After I click on one letter and the new string is getting printed to the page, the letters don't preserve their event listeners. This is the JS code and here is all the code https://codesandbox.io/s/reverse-array-forked-fvclg?file=/src/index.js:0-1316:

```
const appBox = document.getElementById("app");

const convertString = (string) => {
  let stringToArray = string.split("");
  return stringToArray;
};

let stringToArray = convertString("Hello world!");

const printArrayToPage = (string) => {
  string.forEach((element) => {
    const textBox = document.createElement("div");

    if (element !== " ") {
      textBox.classList.add("letter");
    } else {
      textBox.classList.add("emptySpace");
    }

    const text = document.createTextNode(element);
    textBox.appendChild(text);
    appBox.appendChild(textBox);
  });
};

window.onload = printArrayToPage(stringToArray);

const moveLetter = (event) => {
  const targetLetter = event.target;
  const letterToRemove = targetLetter.innerHTML;
  targetLetter.classList.add("invisible");

  if (stringToArray.includes(letterToRemove)) {
    const index = stringToArray.indexOf(letterToRemove);
    stringToArray.splice(index, 1);
  }

  stringToArray.push(letterToRemove);
  appBox.innerHTML = "";
  printArrayToPage(stringToArray);
};

const allLetters = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
allLetters.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener("click", moveLetter));
const allSpaces = document.querySelectorAll(".emptySpace");
allSpaces.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener("click", moveLetter));
```

I tried moving the even assignments (this block)

```
const allLetters = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
allLetters.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener("click", moveLetter));
const allSpaces = document.querySelectorAll(".emptySpace");
allSpaces.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener("click", moveLetter));
```

inside `printArrayToPage` function but because I am using ES6 syntax, I can't use a function before its definition. If I change to functions created used the `function` keyword, everything works as expected. How can I fix this issue using ES6 so that after I click on a letter and the `divs` get re-added to the page, event listeners are re-assigned?

Comment: Suggest you research how to use *"event delegation"*

Comment: Why not just use ES6 `function` declarations? They're more declarative, a bit shorter, and actually work.

Comment: @Bergi you mean this syntax `() => {}`?

Comment: @AriO I mean `function moveLetter(event) {…}` syntax

Comment: @Bergi I thought that's just a standard function declaration? ES6 introduced fat arrow functions, no?

Comment: @charlietfl thank you, this is actually something I didn't know it existed so now I can read about it. Much appreciated.

Comment: @AriO The ES6 standard also introduced new features for `function` declarations. "Using ES6" doesn't mean limiting oneself to the most recent language additions.

Comment: @Bergi I will read more about it, thx. To be honest, 95% of the time I use arrow functions to the point where the regular ones look weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the letter node to the end, you can use the [Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) property, and append the child node to the end. You don't need to create the nodes every time an item is clicked:

```
const moveLetter = (event) => {
  const targetLetter = event.target;
  const parent = targetLetter.parentNode;
  parent.appendChild(targetLetter); // move the element to the end
};
```

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverse-array-forked-lf333?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Here's a simple example snippet:

```js
// adding an event listener to the document
document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  console.clear();
  const origin = evt.target;
  //             ^ where did the event originated?
  if (origin.closest("#bttn1")) {
    console.log("you clicked button#bttn1");
  } else if (origin.closest("#bttn2")) {
    console.log("you clicked button#bttn2")
  }
});

createElement("h3", "header", "Wait 2 seconds...");

// creating buttons after a while. The earlier created
// event listener will detect clicks for the new buttons
setTimeout( () => {
    createElement("button", "bttn1", "click me");
    createElement("button", "bttn2", "click me too");
  }, 2000);

function createElement(nodetype, id, text) { 
  document.body.appendChild(
    Object.assign(document.createElement(nodetype), {id, textContent: text})
  );
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
  margin: 2rem;
}
button {
  margin: 0 0.6rem 0 0;
}
```